# PHP readfile ignores url parameters

Tags: php, url, parameter-passing, readfile

Hi i have an odd problem. I am trying to force files to download by modifying the php headers but my actual problem is that the readfile() function doesn't parse anymore than one url parameter.

eg. readfile('http://localhost/page.mp3?param1=value1&param2=value2');

will give me the error readfile(http://localhost/page.mp3?param1=value1) is forbidden or unavailable. everything past the ampersand (&) is lost.

any solutions?

Comment: Did you try urlencode before passing the url to readfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `&amp;` instead of your single `&` character

Comment: sorry to waste your time but i solved the problem - it was because i was passing the url with parameters as a parameter so that's why it cut off at the & but i'll accept your answer for your time thanks!